# Автоматическое изменение записей в БД

Tags: sql, база-данных

Только начинаю осваивать базы данных.

Придумал себе структуру БД военкомата, на рисунке ниже приведен ее упрощенный макет:

[image: Макет БД]

Идея: в БД хранится информация о призывниках, включая список повесток, которые им были отправлены. И если случается так, что призывник получил 5 повесток и не явился по ним, то его поле *статус* меняется на *уклонист*, и военкомат отправляет по месту его жительства полицию.

Таким образом у меня возникли вопросы по реализации. **Можно ли автоматизировать следующие вещи**:

1. Как только *назначенная_дата_явки* становится меньше текущей даты, поле *проигнорирована* в этой записи приобретает значение *истина*
2. Как только у призывника насчитывается 5 проигнорированных явок, его поле *статус* становится *уклонист*

Возможно ли написать такой запрос, чтобы поля изменялись автоматически с течением времени и в зависимости от связанных с ними данных? Или SQL не способен на это?

Comment: Это не входит в задачи sql вроде бы, я бы сделал это через Celery или просто скриптом в cron

Comment: *Возможно ли написать такой запрос, чтобы поля изменялись автоматически* Нет. Любые изменения в данных производятся только и исключительно при явном выполнении запроса. А вот запрос, изменяющий данные, может быть выполнен и планировщиком - причём в некоторых СУБД имеется свой, встроенный, планировщик.

Comment: Ответ зависит от СУБД. Например, в **oracle** есть возможность создать виртуальную колонку, которая может рассчитываться в зависимости от значения в других столбцах.

Comment: Есть много вариантов решения, но я бы предпочёл явно прописанную  бизнес-логику обёрнутую в транзакцию.